# Can I specify the transform attribute in transition?

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-transforms

**The most usually case would be like this:**

```
    transition: background-color 0.2s,
                transform 1s;
```

**but I want to specify which transform attribute that is controlled by the transition ,like**

```
transition: transform scale 1s,
            transform skew 0.5s,
            transform rotate 2s;
```

I tried this, it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `animation` instead `transition` and set time of all(`1s`+`0.5s`+`2s`) and in `@keyframes`  divide it to time you want to set for each `transform` property

```css
div{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}
div:hover{
 animation: move 2.5s;
}
    @keyframes move {
      0% {
        transform: scale(3);
      }
      35% {
        transform: scale(3) skew(180deg); 
      }
      50%{
       transform: scale(3) skew(180deg) rotate(70deg); 
      }
    }
```

```html
<div></div>
```